# How to connect to a Sybase Advantage Local DB with Java 8

Tags: java, jdbc, java-8, advantage-database-server

We are developing an application and we need to migrate the data from the old db, a Sybase Advantage **Local** DB.

Until now we were doing it with Java 7 and an odbc/jdbc bridge thanks to `java.sql.DriverManager`.
Now we upgraded our application to java 8 and the same driver doesn't work anymore.

Is there any alternative?

Comment: The Google results I've found until now say it is not possible, and that's why I'm asking here. I would have hoped for something like a non official support library, or someone else experience on the topic.

Comment: Ok, I overlooked the “local”. So, do you want a solution to use the ODBC driver on Java 8 or are you looking for a JDBC driver for Sybase Advantage Local DB?

Comment: It would be best to find a JDBC driver so I can use it inside a Linux environment, but I could use a bridge also as I did with Java 7 inside Windows. I need to migrate the data from an Advantage Local DB to a PostgreSQL DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advantage JDBC uses a direct TCP/IP connection to the Advantage server and is not able to connect to Local Server (which is just a DLL).

Comment: Luckily at the end I discovered that the db in production is the server version. If only they had told me sooner I would have avoided a lot of hassle.